# setting datasource to crystal report

Tags: c#, vb.net

i created datatables by code and i added those tables to data set . they working fine .but when i pass this dataset to my report i get nothing .here my codes

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DAL().selectdatatable(String.Format("SELECT PT.PT_Code, PT.age_sex2, PT.fullname2, Ptsense.PT_Date, DR.Dr_Name, Ptsense.sample, Ptsense.G, Ptsense.coun, Ptsense.comm, Ptsense.organism, Ptsense.lowsens FROM (PT INNER JOIN Ptsense ON PT.PT_Code = Ptsense.PT_Code) INNER JOIN DR ON PT.DR_Code = DR.Dr_Code WHERE PT.PT_Code={0} AND Ptsense.PT_Date=#{1}# AND Ptsense.lowsens <>'{2}'", Txtcode.Text, DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), ""))
Dim dt3 As DataTable = New DAL().selectdatatable(String.Format("SELECT  labdetails.labnme, labdetails.labspecial, labdetails.labadress, labdetails.labphone, labdetails.labtime, labdetails.lablogo,labdetails.labnameenglish,labdetails.labspecialenglish  FROM labdetails;"))
Dim dt4 As DataTable = New DAL().selectdatatable(String.Format("SELECT PT.PT_Code, PT.age_sex2, PT.fullname2, Ptsense.PT_Date, DR.Dr_Name, Ptsense.sample, Ptsense.G, Ptsense.coun, Ptsense.comm, Ptsense.organism, Ptsense.lowsens, Ptsense.resis FROM (PT INNER JOIN Ptsense ON PT.PT_Code = Ptsense.PT_Code) INNER JOIN DR ON PT.DR_Code = DR.Dr_Code WHERE PT.PT_Code={0} AND Ptsense.PT_Date=#{1}# AND Ptsense.resis <>'{2}'", Txtcode.Text, DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "")) 
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.Tables.AddRange({dt, dt3, dt4})
rprt.SetDataSource(ds)
```

Comment: which DataTable are you wanting to Bind the Report to .. ds.Tables[0], 1 ,or 2..?

Comment: i want to bind all tables

Comment: what happens if you bind it to the first one `ds.Tables[0]` does it render the data.. if so then you will see how to bind the other two..

Comment: rprt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]).not working

Comment: do a quick google search on how to bind dataset or datatables to Crystal reports there are so many working examples out there.. good luck